# ArcMap not displaying attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

I used to be able to right-click on a layer in the Table of Contents, go to Open Attribute Table, and the attribute table would display.  However, now nothing happens.  The problem occurs regardless of what layer I click on, regardless of what map I'm in.  It does not help to restart the application, or to restart my computer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would suspect that the attribute table is showing up off-monitor. Did you used to use 2 or 3 monitors? See this: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007907

Comment: @mkennedy  Thanks, but my AppData folder was hidden.  Since I could see folders that began with a dot, I thought I was able to see hidden folders, thus I was confused.  cl3's link suggested entering  %APPDATA% in the address bar, and this revealed it.

I do have two monitors, and both are still being used.  Renaming Normal.mxt did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with most bizzare ArcMap cases, a new template (Normal.mxt) will likely solve this issue. You'll lose all of your customized toolbars, but this fix usually solves most of ArcGIS Desktop's weird behaviors.

Instructions can be found here: https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-2121-resetting-your-arcgis-application-profile